# Magento 2.3.3 blank email with html attachment

Tags: email, magento2.3.3, order-confirmation-email

**Since upgrade 2.3.2 to 2.3.3** order confirmation emails are showing empty with attachement.html file attached. The **attachement.html** files shows the order confirmation text which previously appeared in the message. When email with attachment is sent the message text appears in the email. We have already applied the backward compatibility patch. I assume it is a setting somewhere? **Any help is much appreciated.**

Answer (score 4):

I've found the solution.

github.com/magento/magento2/issues/25076

You have to patch the following file:

vendor/zendframework/zend-mail/src/Headers.php

```
$current = $headers;
-        $current->setEncoding($encoding); // Delete this line under $current = $headers;
+        // PATCH
+        //$current->setEncoding($encoding);
+        $current->setEncoding($key === 'contentdisposition' && $current->getFieldValue(false) === 'inline' ? 'ASCII' : $encoding);
+        // ~PATCH
         $this->headers[$index] = $current;
         return $current;
     }
```

Comment: This is a zend framework issue: https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/25076

Comment: I can confirm this works

Comment: Saved my day! Thank you!

Comment: Works for 2.3.4 also, +1