# Override /vendor/zendframework/zend-mail/src/Headers.php file

Tags: magento2, magento2.2.9

In order to fix the following issue temporarily:

[Magento 2.3.3 blank email with html attachment](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/296760/magento-2-3-3-blank-email-with-html-attachment)

I want to override **/vendor/zendframework/zend-mail/src/Headers.php** file. I have tried preferences (using **di.xml**) and composer way (described [here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/136156/how-to-override-a-zend-class)), but could not make it working.

Can anyone help me to override the functionality of this class without hampering upgrade possibilities.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I'm also trying to figure this one out. Not sure how to override a 'src' folder.